# Maclaurin expansion of order 5 of a composite function $\log \frac{\cos x+e}{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

What I’ve tried so far:
$\log \frac{\cos x+e}{x+1}=\log \left( \left( \cos x+e-1 \right)+1 \right)-\log \left( x+1 \right)$,
$\log \left( y+1 \right)=\frac{{{y}^{1}}}{1}-\frac{{{y}^{2}}}{2}+\frac{{{y}^{3}}}{3}-\frac{{{y}^{4}}}{4}+\frac{{{y}^{5}}}{5}+o\left( {{y}^{6}} \right)$,
$\cos x=1-\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{2}+\frac{{{x}^{4}}}{4}+o\left( {{x}^{6}} \right)$
And finally, ${{e}^{x}}=1+x+\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{2!}+\frac{{{x}^{3}}}{3!}+\frac{{{x}^{4}}}{4!}+\frac{{{x}^{5}}}{5!}+o\left( {{x}^{6}} \right)$, so that
$e={{e}^{1}}=2+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{5!}+o\left( {{1}^{6}} \right)$ - I’m not sure about the last one. $e={{e}^{1}}$ is not a function of $x$, rather it is a constant?
I know I must combine these results to calculate $\cos x+e-1$, $\log \left( \cos x+e-1 \right)$ and eventually $\log \left( \left( \cos x+e-1 \right)+1 \right)-\log \left( x+1 \right)$ but I feel really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near $0$, you have$$\cos(x)+e=1+e-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}+O(x^6),$$and, near $1+e$, you have\begin{multline}\log(x)=\log (1+e)+\frac{x-e-1}{1+e}-\frac{(x-e-1)^2}{2(1+e)^2}+\frac{(x-e-1)^3}{3(1+e)^3}+\\-\frac{(x-e-1)^4}{4(1+e)^4}+\frac{(x-e-1)^5}{5(1+e)^5}+O\left((x-e-1)^6\right),\end{multline}and therefore, again near $0$, you have$$\log\bigl(\cos(x)+e\bigr)=\log(1+e)-\frac{x^2}{2(1+e)}+\frac{(-2+e)x^4}{24 (1+e)^2}+O(x^6).$$What I did to get this was to take the Taylor polynomial of order $5$ at $1+e$ of $\log(x)$, to replace $x$ by $1+e-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}$ and to ignore all terms with degree greater than $5$.

On the other hand, we have,near $0$,$$\log(x+1)=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\frac{x^5}5+O\left(x^6\right),$$and so\begin{align}\log\left(\frac{\cos(x)+e}{x+1}\right)&=\log\bigl(\cos(x)+e\bigr)-\log(x+1)\\&=\log(1+e)-x+\frac{ex^2}{2+2e}-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{\left(4+13e+6e^2\right)
   x^4}{24 (1+e)^2}-\frac{x^5}{5}+O\left(x^6\right).\end{align}